# How to get link_to_remote work with jQuery? Ajax is not defined error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to-remote

I'm using Ruby on Rails with jQuery and trying to do the following:

```
    <%= link_to_remote (image_tag("delete.png"),  :url => { :action => 'remove_candidate', :id => candidate }) %>
```

When I load a page and hit the link I get 'Ajax is not defined' error in FireBug console.
I understand that it's because I didn't load prototype, but load jQuery libs instead, but
how I should use it with jQuery then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jrails](http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails)  . That will define all these helpers for you .

Comment: I do use it. Include   <%= javascript_include_tag 'jrails' %>
in layout